# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'databasename'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: laravel

In connection.php Shows error undefined method getDoctrineDriver().

```
    public function getDoctrineSchemaManager() {
        return $this->getDoctrineDriver()->getSchemaManager($this->getDoctrineConnection());
    }

    /**
     * Get the Doctrine DBAL database connection instance.
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection
     */
    public function getDoctrineConnection() {
        if (is_null($this->doctrineConnection)) {
            $data = ['pdo' => $this->getPdo(), 'dbname' => $this->getConfig('database')];

            $this->doctrineConnection = new DoctrineConnection(
                $data, $this->getDoctrineDriver()
            );
        }
        return $this->doctrineConnection;
    }
```

**config/database.php**

```
    <?php
    return [
        'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
        'connections' => [
            /*'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],*/

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mydatabasename'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

    ],

    'redis' => [
        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

**.env**

```
    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_PORT=3306
    DB_DATABASE=mydatabasename
    DB_USERNAME=root
    DB_PASSWORD=
```

getclass() is deprecated in PHP 8 so i managed to use gettype() instead of getclass() in container.php  next run my server its shows a login page and enters the username and password after shows this error I don't know how to fix it!

Comment: Either your credentials are incorrect, or the user does not have permission to access that database.

Comment: i have that db in my localhost

Comment: Yes, but is the `username` and `password` for that `user` of that `database` correct, and does the `user` have the required `privileges`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when changes applied to `.env`file, first, make sure your DB credential and DB Host is set correctly:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE="DB NAME"
DB_USERNAME="root"
DB_PASSWORD=""
```

And if your problem is not solved, try to clear your configuration cache:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

If not solve, restart your server.